# Rails - testing scoped destroy_all ignores scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, destroy, named-scope

I've set up a soft-delete functionality (not using the Paranoia gem): a user can be soft-deleted and then a scoped destroy_all permanently deletes all soft-deleted users. It works in development but I can't get the testing to pass. The test queries with the scope but destroys all users regardless.

The scope in User.rb `scope :only_deleted, -> { where.not(deleted_at: nil) }` finds all soft-deleted users. In the controller, I have:

```
def destroy_soft_deleted
  User.only_deleted.destroy_all
  ...
end
```

I tried this test (and many other combinations):

```
def setup
  @user1 = users(:adam)
  @user2 = users(:beth)
end
test "successful permanent deletion of all soft-deleted users" do
  @user2.soft_delete
  assert_difference "User.count", -1 do
    delete destroy_soft_deleted_users_path
  end
end
```

All other tests pass (e.g. `@user.soft_delete` is tested) and fixtures are good. The test log shows the scope is being used but it deletes both users anyway:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."deleted_at" IS NOT NULL)
DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?[0m  [["id", 585460615]]
DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?[0m  [["id", 911064266]]
```

Here's the test result:

```
"User.count" didn't change by -1.
  Expected: 1
  Actual: 0
```

Does `Model.some_scope.destroy_all` not work in tests? Is there a different assertion I should use?

Comment: i don't know why this is happening, but i can give you an alternative: you can use destroy_all with a parameter, so, in your case:
`User.destroy_all("deleted_at IS NOT NULL")`

Comment: Thanks @MaxForasteiro. I tried it and got an ArgumentError. I looked it up and found in the [release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html) that Rails 5.1 (which I'm using) removed the deprecated parameters for `delete_all` and `destroy_all`.